# How to find Embedded Redis port and kill the Embedded Redis server

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

How to stop the `Embedded Redis` server ? I had just started the redis server and did not implemeneted its stop method. I'm using windows.

How to

1. find the Embedded Redis port ?
2. kill the Embedded Redis server?

Code

```
@Component
public class EmbededRedis {

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startRedis() throws IOException {
        redisServer = new RedisServer(redisPort);
        redisServer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be too late for you but I may help others. I used these command to kill the embedded redis server process.

```
netstat -nao | find "6379"  
taskkill /PID xxxxx /F
```

With xxxxx for your Process ID from the first command.